# Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' from /projectFolder

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, react-native-router-flux, react-native-reanimated

I wanted to use `react-native-router-flux` so i added its dependencies as described in its documents. I also added babel plugin dependency for `react-native-reanimated` in `babel.config.js` as below:

`module.exports = { presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'], plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],};`

But now im getting this error in metro server:

> error: index.js: Cannot find module 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' from '/home/nia/Downloads/YarAb'

my react-native version is 0.63.2

Comment: please include your source code.

Comment: which source code? babel.cofig.js?

Comment: do you get this error when you import `react-native-reanimated/plugin` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, expo sdk v38 doesn't support reanimated v2 yet, because ["reanimated 2 only
supports hermes at the moment"](https://twitter.com/notbrent/status/1266050802025521152).

this problem is also documented in the react-native-reanimated v2 [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/next#known-problems-and-limitations): "expo support is not ready yet, next sdk release will support react native 0.62 – this will allow you to use reanimated 2 in the ejected expo app."

the only solution for the moment is to either eject your expo app in order to use reanimated, or look for [alternatives](https://openbase.io/js/react-native-reanimated/alternatives), like [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable).

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/886

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated

npm start -- --reset-cache

expo start -c
```

worked for me